# preparing update statement based on input parameters dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to prepare update statement dynamically in stored procedure based on 4 input variables.

suppose take `test`, `test1`, `test2` and `test3` are input parameters.

then I have to prepare query like ,please help me to build this:

```
update emp 
   set empid='1' 
 where test = test 
   and test1 = test1 
   and test2 = test2 
   and test3 = test3
```

Suppose if the test and test1 values are null and test2 and test3 values are not null then I can prepare update statement like below

```
update emp 
    set empid='1' 
  where test is null       
    and test1 is null 
    and test2 = test2 
    and test3 = test3
```

Comment: Based on the information you've provided you do not need to form update statement dynamically. Why do you think about dynamic SQL?

Comment: Updated my question Nicholas , sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a change that one or more parameters that you are passing in a procedure are going to be `NULL` you could write your `UPDATE` statement as follows. There is really no need of using dynamic SQL. In this example procedure's parameters are prefixed with `p_`:

```
update emp 
   set empid='1' 
 where (test  = p_test  or (test  is null and p_test  is null)) 
   and (test1 = p_test1 or (test1 is null and p_test1 is null))
   and (test2 = p_test2 or (test2 is null and p_test2 is null)) 
   and (test3 = p_test3 or (test3 is null and p_test3 is null))
```

Comment: thanks , i have to prepare this within sql procedure ,right after this preparation of do i need to use any special caluses to execute this statement.and also why are you checking test is null and p_test is null.what exactly it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL statement based on your input parameters
like

```
 'SELECT '||'Colum_nmae from table' || where var1=var2 .....
```

then use execute immediate to execute this query

Comment: How it will exclude values with null in where condition

Comment: can use var1=nvl(var2,var1) so if var2 is null it will form a always true condition

Answer (score 0):

You can't give your variables the same name as your columns, that would be confusing to PL/SQL. So let's name the variables `v_test`, `v_test1`, ...

You could write:

```
update emp 
       set empid='1'
where  (test  = v_test  OR v_test  is null)
and    (test1 = v_test1 OR v_test1 is null)
and ...
```

Or more simply using NVL:

```
update emp 
       set empid='1'
where  test  = nvl(v_test, test) 
and    test1 = nvl(v_test1, test1) 
and ...
```

`NVL(A, B)` is `A` unless `A` is null in which case it is `B`.